# Android touchpaint api, is this possible?

Tags: android-emulator

i am using the android tocuhpaint api to add some extra functionality to it, like save, send, shake to clear.

How would i go out doing the following.

I want to open a picture from the sd card, lets say my own picture.
right now all i can do is save a  drawing, how do i use a picture? once the picture opens on the screen then i will draw on it.